# C# skips if statement in while loop

Tags: c#, tweetsharp

It's a twitter bot that sends tweet at sunrise/sunset. In only got it to post the first tweet. I've achieved it by using a while loop and two if statements (for each tweet). But it skips the second if statement and only executes the first one. Like it does'nt even execute what is written in the second if statement.

```
while (true)
{
            DateTime localTime = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime test = new DateTime(2020, 9, 11, 9, 53, 0);
            int timeComparison = DateTime.Compare(localTime, test);

            DateTime localTimeTwo = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime testTwo = new DateTime(2020, 9, 11, 9, 53, 15);
            int timeComparisonTwo = DateTime.Compare(localTimeTwo, testTwo);


                bool checkPoint = false;

                if (timeComparison > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(localTime);
                    SendTweet($"< {DateTime.Now} > Sunrise Twitter test ");
                    Console.Read();
                    checkPoint = true;
                }

                if (checkPoint == true && timeComparisonTwo > 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(localTimeTwo);
                    SendTweet($"< {DateTime.Now} > Sunset Twitter test ");
                    Console.Read();
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: `Console.Read();` blocks until a message is entered from console.

Comment: You need to set `checkPoint` outside the loop; you are resetting it to false each time through the loop. Check it with the debugger.

Comment: @PeterSmith that is true, but it will still be true by time it hits the next condition.

Comment: I don't know where you are in the world, but when I run your code (here in UTC-8 timezone), `timeComparison` is `-1`, so `checkPoint` never gets set to `true`. But even if it did, `timeComparisonTwo` is also `-1`. Note that `testTwo` is only `15` seconds later than `test`.